# jQuery Pricing Calculator

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong. The goal is to have the consumer type in the amount of square feet they need for a flooring project and it would output how much their total price would be based on the variables set. I have code written out but it's not running through all of the if else statements.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        // variables
        var firstCase = 60;
        var results = 0;
        var casePrice = 38.17;
        var shares = $("#shares").val();
    
    
        // clear on load
        $("#result").empty();
    
    $("#calculate").on("click", function() {
        if (shares < firstCase) {
            results = casePrice;
        }
    
        else if (shares === firstCase) {
            results = casePrice;
        }
    
        else if (shares <= firstCase * 2 ) {
            results = casePrice * 2;
        }
    
        $("#result").text(results);
    });
    });
```

```css
/* calculator */
.shares {
  max-width: 500px;
  line-height: 300%;
}

.sqft-enter {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.total {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator">
    <label class="sqft-enter">Enter square feet:</label><input name="shares" id="shares" type="text"><button onclick="calculate" id="calculate"> Calculate </button>
    <br>
    <div class="total">
    Total Value: $ 
      <span id="result"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `shares` is a string. Convert it to a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting your `shares` value at the right time. You are getting it once, when the page is ready. That's mean it does not change value when you input something in your `input`.

You need to move that code inside your click function. This way, you are getting your value only when you are clicking the button.

Also, as [j08691 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59684007/jquery-pricing-calculator/59684072#comment105524952_59684007), the `val()` function returns a string, if you wish to compare it to number, you need to parse it into a float.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
        // variables
        var firstCase = 60;
        var results = 0;
        var casePrice = 38.17;
    
    
        // clear on load
        $("#result").empty();
    
    $("#calculate").on("click", function() {
        var shares = parseFloat($("#shares").val());
        if (shares < firstCase) {
            results = casePrice;
        }
    
        else if (shares === firstCase) {
            results = casePrice;
        }
    
        else if (shares <= firstCase * 2 ) {
            results = casePrice * 2;
        }
    
        $("#result").text(results);
    });
    });
```

```css
/* calculator */
.shares {
  max-width: 500px;
  line-height: 300%;
}

.sqft-enter {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.total {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator">
    <label class="sqft-enter">Enter square feet:</label><input name="shares" id="shares" type="text"><button onclick="calculate" id="calculate"> Calculate </button>
    <br>
    <div class="total">
    Total Value: $ 
      <span id="result"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1) `var shares = $("#shares").val();` must be moved to within the "click" event, otherwise that variable will only ever contain the value of the textbox as it stood when the page was loaded (i.e. empty) - it does not automatically update with a new value, you have to read it every time.

2) `shares` is a string when it comes from the textbox. If you try to do maths on a string you may get unexpected results, so you need to parse it to a (floating-point) number before you use it.

Note 1: Your first two `if` statements can be combined into one using `<=` (less than or equal to).

Note 2: There's a still a hole in your logic - if `shares` is greater than `firstCase * 2` then no calculation is performed, because you haven't defined a rule for that. You need an `else` case to catch this situation. I haven't added it because I don't know what calculation you want to perform (or whether you want to output an error or something instead).

Demo fixing issues 1 and 2, and note 1:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // variables
  var firstCase = 60;
  var results = 0;
  var casePrice = 38.17;


  // clear on load
  $("#result").empty();

  $("#calculate").on("click", function() {
    var shares = parseFloat($("#shares").val());

    if (shares <= firstCase) {
      results = casePrice;
    } else if (shares <= firstCase * 2) {
      results = casePrice * 2;
    }

    $("#result").text(results);
  });
});
```

```css
/* calculator */

.shares {
  max-width: 500px;
  line-height: 300%;
}

.sqft-enter {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.total {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator">
  <label class="sqft-enter">Enter square feet:</label><input name="shares" id="shares" type="text"><button onclick="calculate" id="calculate"> Calculate </button>
  <br>
  <div class="total">
    Total Value: $
    <span id="result"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```